# Formatting a date with correct date/time ordering

Tags: java, android, datetime, date, date-format

This is the first time I'm posting on StackOverflow, so please bear with me.

In the Android app I'm working on at the moment, I have to format a `java.util.Date`-style timestamp retrieved from a database according to the user's locale/date format settings.

This sounds simple and can be done with the following piece of code:

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(dateColumn);
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
String dateFormatted = DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(context).format(date);
```

Now, I want the time displayed alongside the date.
Not difficult either, just add:

```
String timeFormatted = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context).format(date);
```

However, I'm hitting a problem here: How do I know which to display first? And what separator do I use?

In most cases, putting the date first and separating the two with a space is a safe bet, I guess.
Is there something equivalent to J2SE's `java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()`?

Answer (score 0):

Do smth like:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kkmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Here's formatting of current date/time - source I hope is selfexplanatory

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this doesn't solve my problem: I want to format a combined date time exactly the way it's configured in the user's locale settings. `java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance` does this, but it's standard Java API and might not implement all the Android localization specifics.